# Does there exist English letter frequency charts based on the assumed age of the reader?

Tags: statistics, coding-theory

**Has anyone done work to construct letter frequency charts based on the assumed age of the reader?**

One would expect that letter usage would be different in books targeted at (for example) a 3rd grader vs a college student.

My first grade daughter loves the show "Pokemon".  In that show the Pokemon characters only speak sounds that are made form pieces of their name.  For example a Pikachu pokemon only speaks words made from combinations of the sounds "Pi", "Ka", and "Chu".  She thought it would be cool to make a real Pikachu language.  And I think its a good opportunity to teach her about encoding schemes.

The obvious choice is encoding letters of the alphabet using these three sounds.  Ideally one would want the length of the words to be minimized.  We have three sounds, therefore a ternary Huffman code based on an English letter frequency chart would provide an optimal code.

I have seen many charts (like this one) ...

[http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html)

Based on that chart, here is the code I came up with so far.
[image]

... but this chart is based on generic data and therefore wouldn't be optimal in terms of the words a first grader would choose speak.

This would be a spoken language only, so there is no need to encode special symbols or different letter cases.  I am only interested in the frequency of English letters English letters A-Z.

Ideally I want to find a table based on 1st grade books.  But tables based on text from any elementary school grade would be acceptable.

Comment: Interesting question but off-topic for this site.  It might be on-topic at https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @EricWofsey  I see your point.  This isn't a pure math question, but its also not a pure English question.  If I went to the English site and started asking them about probability tables for constructing a Huffman code they would send me back to the Math site.  The fact that this question is asking about English letters is just a detail.  Someone could ask the same question for any language.  At this point I am not sure on which site would be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the letter frequencies would vary a lot from book to book, especially in those with a very limited vocabulary.  A 1st grade reader about Dick and Jane would have an unusually high frequence of "J".  I don't know if the texts of many of those readers
are readily available online, but if you can find them it's easy to compute the letter frequencies.

EDIT: Well, [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks) has lots of old readers and other children's books available for plain-text download.